# parallelism of vector bundles

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

Let $E, F$ vector bundles over some differential manifold M. Let $h=(h^{1},…,h^{n}): E \to F $ a bundle homomorphism. How I can characterize the parallelism of $h$ in terms of $h^{i}$ ?

Comment: About your notation: Are you assuming that $F$ admits a basis of global sections, and these $h^i$ express $h$ in that basis?

Comment: Hi jao: Please revise this question, including responsing to Ben McKay's question, and also including motivation so on, as suggested in http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/70/how-to-ask-page. I expect this question will be closed as "unclear what you're asking"; if it is closed, revisions will automatically nominate it for reopening.

Answer (score 1):

If we take a basis $\sigma_A$ of local sections of $E$, any connection on $E$ is expressed as $\nabla \sigma_A = \gamma^B_A \sigma_B$, where $\gamma^B_A$ are the connection 1-forms. On $E^*$, the induced connection has connection 1-forms $\nabla \sigma^A = - \gamma^A_B \otimes \sigma^B$. Write the connection on $F$ as $\nabla \tau_i=\eta^j_i \otimes \tau_j$. On $E^* \otimes F$, $\nabla (\sigma^A \otimes \tau_i) = -\gamma^A_B \otimes \sigma^B \otimes \tau_i + \eta_{ij} \sigma^B \otimes \tau_j$. Any morphism of vector bundles $h \colon E \to F$ is locally expressed as $h(\sigma_A)=h^i_A \tau_i$, so $\nabla h = dh^i_A \sigma^A \tau_i + h^i_A (-\gamma^A_B \otimes \sigma^B \otimes \tau_i + \eta_{ij} \sigma^B \otimes \tau_j)$.

Comment: Ben, thank you for your attention. I'm actually thinking of an orthonormal frame $ (E_1, ..., E_m) $ with $ h: TM \to F $ given by $h (X) = \sum h^{i} (X) E_i$

Comment: Strange notation: to use $E_i$ for a basis of sections of $F$, not of $E$. Just change my notation to yours: my $\tau_i$ are your $E_i$. Then the $\eta_{ij}$ are antisymmetric (because the $E_i$ are orthonormal), but that doesn't affect the computation above at all.